# Routing for country , province , city , product in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

This url structure is proposed for SEO optimization. So suggesting another structure will not work. Structure proposed is

`example.com/<language>/<country>/<province>/<city>/<product>`

`example.com/en/spain` I wish to point to `CountryController` `indexAction` , as view of each one is different, and sometimes think there is change in layout also.

Show the content in English language about the country Spain. And for a request `example.com/en/india` should show about India in English language and `example.com/es/spain` should show the spanish page for the country Spain.

`example.com/en/spain/barcelona` Points to `CountryController` `provinceAction`

Content Page for the Barcelona province of Spain in English Language .

`example.com/en/spain/barcelona/barcelona` Points to `CountryController` `cityAction`

Content Page for the Barcelona city in Barcelona province of country Spain in English Language .

`example.com/en/spain/barcelona/barcelona/taxis` Points to `CountryController` `productAction`

Content Page for the product in Barcelona city , Barcelona province of country Spain in English Language .

Yes we can add a route like

```
$router = $ctrl->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'country_spain',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('spain',
                                     array('controller' => 'country',
                                           'action' => 'index'))
);
```

But in this case we need to add the whole list of countries to the route. ie india , china , pakistan , unitedstates etc .

Then will be adding country_province

```
$router = $ctrl->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'country_spain_barcelona',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('spain',
                                     array('controller' => 'country',
                                           'action' => 'province'))
);
```

So if we have 50 province it will be horrible to add count of countries multiplied by count of provinces for the countries , and this will become more routes when moving to city and products.

You may say add something like

```
$router = $ctrl->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'country',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('country/:country/:province/:city/:product',
                                     array('controller' => 'country',
                                           'action' => 'index'))
);
```

But in this case its like we will be pointing to same action, but as the view of the requests change, and this will become a fat controller .

The problem with [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) is we should have something like 
`example.com/en/country/spain/barcelona/barcelona/taxis` and also the all moves to a single action. As the view is entirely different, it becomes dirty. May be something like partials I can use. But I wonder whether there is another good solution for the problem to solve this. This is a legacy project, so I have limitations on it and #ZF version is 1.6.

There is an example something similar

http://www.travelportal.info/
http://www.travelportal.info/asia
http://www.travelportal.info/asia/india
http://www.travelportal.info/asia/india/business-currency-economy

How do you think, they have done this, will they have added routes atleast for asia , europe like that ?

I was able to make it work like

`example.com/en/spain` Pointing to `CountryController` `indexAction`

`example.com/en/spain/barcelona` Pointing to `CountryController` `provinceAction`

`example.com/en/spain/barcelona/barcelona` Pointing to `CountryController` `cityAction`

`example.com/en/spain/barcelona/barcelona/taxis` Pointing to `CountryController` `productAction`

But there I need to add 4 routes and this will become hard to manually add the route like this.

Suggestions and criticisms are welcome to make it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you want a separate route for each of your example scenarios, e.g.:

```
$router->addRoute(
    'product',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/:country/:province/:city/:product', array(
        'controller' => 'country',
        'action' => 'product'
    ))
);

$router->addRoute(
    'city',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/:country/:province/:city', array(
        'controller' => 'country',
        'action' => 'city'
    ))
);

$router->addRoute(
    'province',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/:country/:province', array(
        'controller' => 'country',
        'action' => 'province'
    ))
);

$router->addRoute(
    'country',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/:country', array(
        'controller' => 'country',
        'action' => 'index'
    ))
);
```

Comment: +1 Right on. Standard routes - in the right order! - should handle it. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I am not sure why I didn't thought about this, I will try to work on the above solution on Monday and report back. But a quick and simple question, what will happen if I have already a route with `$router->addRoute(
    'differentroute',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/:something', array(
        'controller' => 'somecontroller',
        'action' => 'index'
    ))
);` Which route will it take ?

Comment: Sorry the problem with this route is all the routes will move to country controller. There are more routes in it :( .

Comment: Finally I made some changes like adding 'en' than ':lang' for the last route. This way we can have a default controller :)